# Getting "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'"

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, country-codes

I had inherited a website to do general maintenance on. The web pages are ASP pages but the bulk of my work has been with the html/css. The site has been working fine for a number of years, that is until now. When I try to load pages that are containing VB script I receive the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: '[object]'
>
> /new_products.asp, line 12

the name of the asp page changes based on the page that is being called, but the line reference is the same.

The code that is generating the error is as follows:

```
        Dim objXMLHTTP
    Dim coordinates
    Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    ip = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.ippages.com/xml/?ip="&ip&"&get=country", False
    objXMLHTTP.Send
    Set xmldoc = objXMLHTTP.responseXML
    country = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("ip_address/lookups/lookup_country").text
    set objXMLHTTP=nothing

    theCountry = Trim(UCASE(country))


    If theCountry = "CA-CANADA" then
        Bags = "13.99"
        SB4Pack = "14.00"
        currency_code = "CAD"
        lc = "CA"
        Pref = "$"
        ShipType = 1
    ElseIf theCountry = "US-UNITED STATES" then
        Bags = "13.99"
        SB4Pack = "14.00"
        currency_code = "USD"
        lc = "US"
        Pref = "$"
        ShipType = 2
    Else
        Bags = "8.00"
        SB4Pack = "11.00"
        currency_code = "GBP"
        lc = "UK"
        Pref = "&#163;"
        ShipType = 2
    End If
```

With my extremely limited knowledge of VB I have done my best to try and figure out why the code has stopped working, but I am stumped. Any and all help is greatly greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an environment specific issue which started to popup recently as you mentioned... No sure statement can be provided. You need to investigate it. What one can do is to suggest some thing. I believe your problem is one of this statement.

```
Set xmldoc = objXMLHTTP.responseXML
country = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("ip_address/lookups/lookup_country").text
```

Probably this value is not coming or Null or Nothing.Try to print the value of country if it's coming as Null, Nothing... Later when you try to change the case of country.... You can use tools to capture the Http request and response tools like Fidler to verify what is coming in lookup_country as a value or whether you are getting this node or not.

Also where is **`theCountry`** is declared. If it's dynamic variable then check if some one enabled OptionExplicit??

Comment: Thank you having taken the time to respond. I apologize for not having gotten back to you until now. I was not able to pursue the solution to the problem as the client decided to close up shop and the website was no longer needed. Thanks again though.